# Unable to print recursive fibonacci sequence correctly

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to write a recursive Fibonacci generator that prints each term in C. The number of terms is user-specified; I have developed the algorithm. When I try to print, it only prints ones. Can anyone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Fibonacci (int n)
{
    if (n = 0)
        return 0;
    if (n = 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (Fibonacci(n-1) + Fibonacci(n-2));
}

int main()
{
    int terms;
    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%d", &terms);


    printf("\nThe Fibonacci sequence containing %d terms is:\n", terms);

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < terms; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", Fibonacci(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like homework to me.  We're not against helping people with homework, just tag it as homework so we know how to guide you.

Comment: @DanielRudy The [homework] tag is not supposed to be used anymore.

Comment: @Xufox I was not aware of that.  Well, if it is homework, it should be mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (n == 0)
```

not

```
if (n=0)
```

check your syntax careful.

Answer (score 1):

You use a single equal sign and so you assign a value instead of doing a comparison

```
if (n == 0)
    return 0;
if (n == 1)
    return 1;
...
```

Comment: if (0 == n) is even better. This way if you use = instead of == it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic :

```
int Fibonacci (int n)
{
    if(n < 2)
       return n;
    else
       return Fibonacci(n- 1) + Fibonacci(n- 2);
}
```

Here `n<2` means the recursion will terminate when number of terms are `< 2` because we know the first two terms of fibonacci series are `0` and `1`.